# Regex for non-capturing optional

Tags: python, regex

I'm a newbie and I've been stuck on this for days. I want to use extract in Python to normal sentences without URLs.
For instance:

```
1st text: '(some normal sentences...) https://www.(...)'  
2nd text: '(some normal sentences...) '
```

When I use `r'([\w+\.\s\W\@w]+)(?:https)'`  it will catch sentences in 1st text only.

When I use `r'([\w+\.\s\W\@w]+)(?:https)?'` it will catch sentences in 2nd text and all text of 1st text.

Can someone please help with my Regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `non greedy` regex like,

```
>>> import re
>>> x
"1st text: '(some normal sentences...) https://www.(...)\n2nd text: '(some normal sentences...)"
>>> print(x)
1st text: '(some normal sentences...) https://www.(...)
2nd text: '(some normal sentences...)
>>> re.findall(r'\(\w.+?\)', x)
['(some normal sentences...)', '(some normal sentences...)']
>>> re.findall(r'\((\w.+?)\)', x)
['some normal sentences...', 'some normal sentences...']
```